# How to assign the value of a register to the CF?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, carryflag

Say I need to save and restore the value in CF.

I know one technique is to use `pushf`and `popf`. But this is way too expensive for me, as I *only* need CF.

I am trying to use one single register to do this. For saving, I used `setc %r12b`. However, I don't know how to retrieve this value, that is, **how to do something like** `mov %r12b CF`?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How about `shr %r12b`.

Comment: Thanks!! Does this impact other registers? Or CF only?

Comment: Yes, it does. See the instruction set reference.

Comment: Why not lahf and sahf? What do ypu mean by expensive?

Comment: `lahf` is not necessarily available in 64 bit mode, unless you have it as an extension (see `cpuid`).

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Jester, you can do a `shr %r12b` because

> For each shift count, the least significant bit of the destination
>   operand is shifted into the CF flag, and the most significant bit is
>   either set or cleared depending on the instruction type.

http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html